# Getting text from multiple paragraphs when there is no class defined with beautiful soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape a few paragraphs from a page with beautiful soup.

My problem is:

- there are no styles defined, except for the parent div.
- As I loop through pages, the number of paragraphs is not constant.

The html below is an extraction from this page, which is one of the pages in my range:
`https://www.jonathanball.co.za/component/virtuemart/joining-the-dots-an-unofficial-biography-of-pravin-gordhan?Itemid=491`

So what I need is to extract all the `<p><span>some text</span></p>` between the `<h2>` and the first `<table>`

This is what I tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = '''
<div class="bd-productdesc-13">
    <hr>
    <h2><span>Author 1 Name</span></h2>
    <hr>
    <p><span>Paragraph 1</span></p>
    <p><span>Paragraph 2</span></p>
    <p><span>Paragraph 3</span></p>
    <p><span>Paragraph 4</span></p>
    <p><span>Paragraph 5</span></p>
    <p><span>Paragraph 6</span></p> 
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><span></span></p>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><span></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p><strong>Jonathan Ancer</strong> is an award-winning journalist</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <p><span></span></p>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Category:</strong>&nbsp;</span></td>
                <td><span>Politics, Current Affairs</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>ISBN:</strong>&nbsp;</span></td>
                <td><span>9781776191055</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Publisher:</strong>&nbsp;</span></td>
                <td><span>Jonathan Ball Publishers</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
author = soup.find('h2').text.strip()
para = soup.find_all('p')

for desc in para :
    print(desc.get_text())

# print(author, description)
```

The result is:

```
Paragraph 1
Paragraph 2
Paragraph 3
Paragraph 4
Paragraph 5
Paragraph 6
 

I DONT WANT THIS PARAGRAPH
```

What I want is:

```
Author 1 Name, Paragraph 1 \n Paragraph 2 \n Paragraph 3 \n Paragraph 4 \n Paragraph 5 \n Paragraph 6
```

Comment: There is no `Author 1 Name` in your html; do you mean `Jonathan Ancer &amp; Chris Whitfield`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I changed it on my side on order to simplify the code, will edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the html in your question and using css selectors, this

```
for t in soup.select('h2 span, hr ~ p span'):
    print(t.text)
```

should output

```
Author 1 Name
Paragraph 1
Paragraph 2
Paragraph 3
Paragraph 4
Paragraph 5
Paragraph 6
```